# Массив с объектом в массиве с объектом

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с объектами:

```
paramsCity: [
    {
      id: '5700000100000',
      name: 'Орёл',
      label: 'Орёл',
      zip: 302042,
      typeShort: 'г',
      parents: [
        {
          id: '5700000000000',
          name: 'Орловская',
          zip: 302042,
          type: 'Область',
          typeShort: 'обл',
          okato: '54000000000'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: '2100600004100',
      name: 'Орел',
      zip: 429708,
      typeShort: 'п',
      parents: [
        {
         id: "2100000000000",
         name: "Чувашская",
         zip: 428009,
         type: "Республика",
         typeShort: "Респ",
         okato: "97000000000",
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Как перебрать массив так, чтобы добраться до name в массиве parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paramsCity.forEach(c => c.parents.forEach(p => console.log(p.name)));
```

```js
const paramsCity = [{
    id: '5700000100000',
    name: 'Орёл',
    label: 'Орёл',
    zip: 302042,
    typeShort: 'г',
    parents: [{
      id: '5700000000000',
      name: 'Орловская',
      zip: 302042,
      type: 'Область',
      typeShort: 'обл',
      okato: '54000000000'
    }]
  },
  {
    id: '2100600004100',
    name: 'Орел',
    zip: 429708,
    typeShort: 'п',
    parents: [{
      id: "2100000000000",
      name: "Чувашская",
      zip: 428009,
      type: "Республика",
      typeShort: "Респ",
      okato: "97000000000",
    }, ]
  }
];

paramsCity.forEach(c => c.parents.forEach(p => console.log(`${c.name}, ${p.name} ${p.type}`)));
```